# Pull Request Merged After Branch Deletion

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I’m working on a project that uses Bitbucket. I branched from the master to add a feature, created a pull request, and at some point before the PR was approved there ended up being some merge conflicts that had been brought into the master.

Long story short, I ended up just deleting my branch, but that ended up showing the PR as being “merged” with it pointing to the commit right before I branched. Nothing really has been “merged”.

Is this the intended behavior? I suppose I could have just declined the PR, but I had assumed I could create a new branch (identical changes from me with the new changes from the master) and associate it to the PR. Deleting the branch seems to be the wrong move here. what should I have done here?

Comment: The better thing to do in your case is to resolve the conflicts on the same branch, be either rebasing feature onto master, or by merging master into feature. (Then resolve the conflicts locally.) If you rebase you'll need to force push your branch, and with merge you can just regular push. After the push the PR will be updated without conflicts. You can still do this even though you deleted your remote branch. Just continue with your local branch (or recreate it from the same commit it was on before).

Comment: As for the PR showing "merged" when the source branch is deleted... that seems wrong to me. I wouldn't expect that to be normal behavior and I wonder if something else happened, like maybe the same commits were merged into `master` in another PR?